# how to reorder groups of listview of windows forms in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

how to reorder dynamically added groups based on group header of  listview of windows forms in c# ?

Comment: Could you clarify that a little more? Some code showing how you're adding items to the listview would be helpful, at least to know what kind of object you're loading in to the view.

Comment: Please don't be so liberal with putting every single tag of different versions of the language.  It is way too excessive (especially after seeing your question history).  If it's just a general C# question, just put the [c#] tag alone.  If it is specific to version 3.0, then use the associated [c#-3.0] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ListViewItemSorter to designate a class to do the sorting as items are added to the listview.